# Why did it say UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment? a is a global variable. (Python)

Tags: python, error-handling, global-variables, local-variables

```
#assigning a global variable
a = 1

#defining a function that use the global variable
def main():
    while a <= 10:
        a += 1
 
#calling the function       
main()
```

Console: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it's `a` global in function. When you want to change the value of global variable inside function.

```
a = 1 

def main():
    global a
    while a<=10:
        a+=1

main()
```